# Call sourced file's functions in bash script

Tags: environment-variables, bash-scripting, export

I have a bash file, `src-useful.bash`, containing useful functions such as `say_hello()`,located in /path/to/useful.

In my `~/.bash_profile` I added the following lines:

```
export BASH_USEFUL=/path/to/useful
source $BASH_USEFUL/src-useful.bash
```

Opening a new terminal I can check the following:

```
$ echo $BASH_USEFUL
/path/to/useful

$ cat $BASH_USEFUL/src-useful.bash
function hello() {
    echo "hello!"
}

$ hello
hello!
```

I created a script, `say_hello.sh`:

```
$ cat say_hello.sh
echo "BASH_USEFUL: $BASH_USEFUL"
hello

$ ./say_hello.sh
BASH_USEFUL: /path/to/useful  # Recognizsed
say_hello.sh: line 2: say_hello: command not found  # Not recognized?
```

If I source `$BASH_USEFUL/src-useful.bash` in `say_hello.sh` it will work however:

```
$ cat say_hello.sh
echo "BASH_USEFUL: $BASH_USEFUL"
source $BASH_USEFUL/src-useful
say_hello

$ ./say_hello.sh
BASH_USEFUL: /path/to/useful  # Recognized
hello!  # Function say_hello is now recognized
```

I would like to know why the variable `BASH_USEFUL` is still recognized by my script, while the functions from my sourced file cannot be seen in the environment by my running script. Is there a workaround apart from sourcing my `src-useful.bash` in my scripts? I would like `src-useful.bash`'s functions to be loaded in the environment of any script I launch.

Comment: Seems you changed the call to the sourced function ```hello()``` to ```say_hello()``` in the steps above...

Comment: Ah yes thanks I corrected it. The problem is still here though

Comment: That's...a _horrible_ way to write programs. It'll bite you sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks grawity, how should I source my generic functions then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only exported environment items are copied to new child environments.
You exported `BASH_USEFUL` so this env-var is copied to your `./say_hello.sh` sub process as expected. But you did not do the same for your function `hello()` which is then a simple local symbol not to be copied in new child environments.

Syntax to export functions using bash uses the `-f` argument of `export`:

```
export -f hello
```

Comment: So that means I sould either manually export all the functions (yuk) or source the file in all my scripts?

Comment: Yes. But exporting all functions can be quite easy if you think about that when you write your scripts. You can either:

1) add a `export -f` after each function body, or
2) add a `MYSCRIPT_FUNCS="${MYSCRIPT_FUNCS} foo"` after each function body with an extra helper function `myscript_export_all()` which calls `export -f` on all tokens of this variable for example. And import this script using a syntax like `source myscript.sh && myscript_export_all`.